# Is it possible use Facebook API developing via Android emulator?

Tags: android, facebook

I have no physical device. Is it possible to test Facebook api in emulator? I guess Facebook app needs to be installed, but I can not install it via Google Play. Why?

Comment: No, it doesn't need the facebook app. Did you try using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every release of the Facebook SDK for Android with the native Share dialog also includes an APK for the Facebook app.

This APK was in the SDK download until release 3.14.1. After this time it became a separate download. You can find the APKs on our [download page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads).

Simply install the Facebook APK on your Android emulator or device and test the native Share dialog from your app.

This post is referenced from the [developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting).